# Logical in my R function always returns "TRUE"

Tags: r, logic, boolean-logic

I'm trying to write an R function that calculates whether a data subject is eligible for subsidies based on their income (`X_INCOMG`), the size of their household (`household` calculated from `CHILDREN` and `NUMADULT`), and the federal poverty limit for their household size (`fpl_matrix`).  I use a number of `if` statements to evaluate whether the record is eligible, but for some reason my code is labeling everyone as eligible, even though I know that's not true.  Could someone else take a look at my code?

Note that the coding for the variable `X_INCOMG` denotes income categories (less than $15000, 25-35000, etc).

#Create a sample data set

```
   sampdf=data.frame(NUMADULT=sample(3,1000,replace=T),CHILDREN=sample(0:5,1000,replace=T),X_INCOMG=sample(5,1000,replace=T))

#Introducing some "impurities" into the data so its more realistic
    sampdf[sample(1000,3),'CHILDREN']=13
    sampdf[sample(1000,3),'CHILDREN']=NA
    sampdf[sample(1000,3),'X_INCOMG']=9

    #this is just a matrix of the federal poverty limit, which is based on household size
    fpl_2004=matrix(c(
        1,9310,
        2,12490,
        3,15670,
        4,18850,
        5,22030,
        6,25210,
        7,28390,
        8,31570,
        9,34750,
        10,37930,
        11,41110),byrow=T,ncol=2)

        ##################here is the function I'm trying to create

    fpl250=function(data,fpl_matrix,add_limit){   #add_limit is the money you add on for every extra person beyond a household size of 11

        data[which(is.na(data$CHILDREN)),'CHILDREN']=99 #This code wasn't liking NAs so I'm coding NA as 99

        data$household=data$CHILDREN+data$NUMADULT #calculate household size

        for(i in seq(nrow(data))){
        if(data$household[i]<=11){data$bcccp_cutoff[i]=2.5*fpl_matrix[data$household[i],2]}  #this calculates what the subsidy cutoff should be, which is 250% of the FPL
            else{data$bcccp_cutoff[i]=2.5*((data$household[i]-11)*add_limit+fpl_matrix[11,2])}}

        data$incom_elig='yes'  #setting the default value as 'yes', then changing each record to 'no' if the income is definitely more than the eligibility cutoff

        for(i in seq(nrow(data))){
            if(data$X_INCOMG[i]=='1' | data$X_INCOMG[i]=='9'){data$incom_elig='yes'} #This is the lowest income category and almost all of these people will qualify
            if(data$X_INCOMG[i]=='2' & data$bcccp_cutoff[i]<15000){data$incom_elig[i]='no'}
            if(data$X_INCOMG[i]=='3' & data$bcccp_cutoff[i]<25000){data$incom_elig[i]='no'}
            if(data$X_INCOMG[i]=='4' & data$bcccp_cutoff[i]<35000){data$incom_elig[i]='no'}
            if(data$X_INCOMG[i]=='5' & data$bcccp_cutoff[i]<50000){data$incom_elig[i]='no'}
            if(data$household[i]>90){data$incom_elig[i]='no'}
            }
        return(data)
        }

    dd=fpl250(sampl,fpl_2004,3180)
    with(dd,table(incom_elig))  #it's coding all except one as eligible
```

I know this is a lot of code to digest, but I appreciate whatever help you have to offer!

Comment: Don't start with a function, it just complicates things. Write your code so it works outside of a function, then put it in a function.

Comment: I don't have time to take your code apart now, but some other quick comments: 1. Are you worried about turning households with no children into very large households by coding the number of children as 99? Better to make the `NA`s work. 2. You don't need for loops for any of this. 3. Rather than `if`, you might like `ifelse`. Work through the examples at the bottom of `ifelse` and I bet you'll understand. 4. If you still need help, isolate your problem, and describe to us *in words* what the criteria are.

Comment: Doesn't appear to have sufficient data to run the code. did you misspell the dataframe name?

Comment: And there is no `bcccp_cutoff` variable.

Comment: And the X_INCOMG variable is insufficiently defined to do anything with.

Comment: Well, gosh... what is actually **in** `data$household` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to get the logic working well outside of a function first, then wrap it in a function once it is all working well. My code below does this.

I think one issue was you had the literal comparisons to X_INCOMG as strings (`data$X_INCOMG[i]=='1'`). That field is a numeric in your sample code, so remove the quotes. Try using a coded factor for X_INCOMG as well. This will make your code easier to manage later.

There is no need to loop over each row in the data frame.

```
#put the poverty level data in a data frame for merging
fpl_2004.df<- as.data.frame(fpl_2004)
names(fpl_2004.df)<-c("household","pov.limit")
#Include cutoffs
fpl_2004.df$cutoff = 2.5 * fpl_2004.df$pov.limit

add_limit=3181

#compute household size (if NA's this will skip them)
sampdf$household = numeric(nrow(sampdf))
cc<-which(complete.cases(sampdf))
sampdf$household[cc] = sampdf$NUMADULT[cc] + sampdf$CHILDREN[cc]

#get max household and fill fpl_2004 frame
max.hh<-max(sampdf$household,na.rm=TRUE)
#get the 11 person poverty limit
fpl11=subset(fpl_2004.df,household==11)$pov.limit
#rows to fill out the data frame
append<-data.frame(household=12:max.hh,pov.limit=numeric(max.hh-12+1),
               cutoff=2.5 *(((12:max.hh)-11)*add_limit+fpl11))
fpl_2004.df<- rbind(fpl_2004.df,append)

#merge the two data frames
sampdf<- merge(sampdf,fpl_2004.df, by="household",all.x=TRUE)

#Add a logical variable to hold the eligibility                          
sampdf$elig <- logical(nrow(sampdf))
#compute eligibility
sampdf[!is.na(sampdf$X_INCOMG) & sampdf$X_INCOMG == 1,"elig"] = TRUE
sampdf[!is.na(sampdf$X_INCOMG) & sampdf$X_INCOMG == 9,"elig"] = TRUE
#for clarity define variable of what to subset
lvl2 <-!is.na(sampdf$X_INCOMG) & sampdf$X_INCOMG == 2
lvl2 <- lvl2 & !is.na(sampdf$cutoff) & sampdf$cutoff>=15000
#set the eligibility (note the initial value was false thus cutoff logic reversed)
sampdf[lvl2,"elig"] = TRUE

#continue computing these
lvl3 <-!is.na(sampdf$X_INCOMG) & sampdf$X_INCOMG == 3
lvl3 <- lvl3 & !is.na(sampdf$cutoff) & sampdf$cutoff>=25000
sampdf[lvl3,"elig"] = TRUE
```

Alternately you could load in a small data frame with the cutoff comparison values (15000; 25000; 35000 etc) and the X_INCOMG. Then merge by X_INCOMG, as I did with the household size, and set all the values in one go like this the below. You may need to use `complete.cases` again.

```
sampdf$elig = sampdf$cutoff >= sampdf$comparison.value
```

You will then have `elig == FALSE` for any incomplete cases, which will need further investigation.

Comment: I learned a lot from your post!  I know from the comments above that my post could have been a lot clearer, so thank you for figuring out what I was trying to do!